# Android charts - what can I use?

Tags: android, charts

what is best library for drawing charts in Android?

It should be charts with dates on x-axis. Consists of values valid for specific time interval. For example - value "5.5" would be valid from 4pm 5.1. 2014 to 6pm 12.1 2014 and so on.

It would nice to have some scaling, like hours, days, months, years, when user would use zoom.

I would like to have bar chart and cubic line chart.

Thanks for tips !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit this link.It has lots of libraries.
https://android-arsenal.com/

Answer (score 1):

I used https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/ and https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

AChartEngine is easy to use, MPAndroidChart has more option but is less easy to use than AChartEngine

Comment: Yes I know about AChartEngine.. And I have been trying to make bar chart with dates last day, but I don't know how to do that with AChartEngine, is that even possible to have chart with zoom witch would showing hours/days/months depends on zoom??